# How to force Stockfish to make mistake

Tags: stockfish, uci

I developed a bot. It had a 100% win rate and my account was banned. I need to get it to make mistakes but can't force Stockfish to do it. How can I modify Stockfish to make mistakes?

Comment: What is "100%wr"? And banned on what site for what reason did they give you? I will not be able to answer as it is not my specialty, but these things need to be known.

Comment: I would like to know why before I just take lichess' word for it.

Comment: There's no engine that can win 100% of the time. Anyone claiming otherwise should prove it in a fair competition like TCEC.

Comment: I imagine he means his engine is cheating against humans on a chess website. Stockfish can easily win 100% of the time against the average human. I've voted to close as well.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation behind using an engine someone else wrote. That's kind of like riding a city bus to beat people in a footrace. It might "work" if you don't get caught, but what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

```
setoption name Skill Level value 1
go
setoption name Skill Level value 20
```